# ZipArchive Reference Breaks WIndows Service TImer

Tags: c#, windows, service, c#-ziparchive

I'm new here and new to C#.  I work for a retailer and have been stuck in visual studio 6 until this year but now I'm self-teaching c# and rewriting everything that I've done for the past 21 years.  Don't you wish you were me? :{

Anyway, I have a Windows service that periodically executes a series of jobs that create files. When those jobs complete, the service creates a zip file from them and notifies a server at corporate to collect and delete the zip file.  I've been struggling with this service for a couple of days now because the timer event won't fire.  So I stripped it down to bare metal -- a timer and an event handler -- and that worked.  I then started adding back in the worker code a little at a time until I narrowed down to the section of code that is causing the issue.  It's the ZipArchive call.  Everything works until I uncomment the following code, specifically the "using ( var archive ... ))" block

```
var transmissionFiles = Directory.GetFiles( _uploadDirectory, "*.trx" );
if (transmissionFiles.Length > 0)
{
    using (var zipfile = new FileStream( $"{_uploadDirectory}zp" +
        $"{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd}.{_storeNumber:D4}.{DateTime.Now:HHmmss}", FileMode.Open ))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive( zipfile, ZipArchiveMode.Update ))
        {
            foreach (var tFile in transmissionFiles)
            {
                archive.CreateEntry( tFile );
                File.Delete( tFile );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not like the using statement in c#.  It masks the exception messages. I rather put the code into a exception handler (try/catch) which displays the errors rather than continuing and not given an error. Looking at your code I suspect you are getting an error because you are trying to delete a file that is being using.  You have to make sure the file is closed before trying to delete.

Comment: update:  I tried making the ZipArchive reference a class variable but no effect.  The timer event never fires

Comment: I removed the File.Delete( ... ) but no effect.  The whole method is in a try/catch and no exceptions are thrown

Comment: but there are log events at the top of the event handler that never occur including a debug write to file <code>    using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter( "c:\\temp\\testtimer.txt", true ))
    {
        fileWriter.WriteLine( $"timer fired at {eventArgs.SignalTime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" );
    }
</code>

Comment: Start with adding a try/catch around the using var archive block, log the exeption and if not null also the innerException. It will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Again, there is a debug write to file at the top of the method.  It never runs.

Comment: @jdweng since when does a `using` mask an exception and continue on without an error? If an exception is throw it'll be noticed, with the same message it'd have without a `using`. Nothing is swallowing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by moving the ZipArchive references to a separate method. Something about having those calls in the timer event handler is not working.  Weird

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateFromDirectory(String, String)` to archive a directory

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: CreateFromDirectory( ) doesn't have the ability to exclude files and there could be files in the directory that don't belong in the zip